# How to increase memory limit in wp-config.php

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-500, memory-limit

I'm trying to increase the memory limit in the `wp-config.php` file, but I don't have the necessary permissions to edit the file. The line defining the memory limit appears to be missing, making it more challenging to address this issue.

Is there a way to increase the memory limit for this script without directly editing the file itself? If so, what are the alternative methods or workarounds that I can use to achieve this?

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: why don't you have permission to edit `wp-config.php`?

Comment: Im not sure, but when I tried to replace wp-config.php with version that was edited to my needs, it didn't allow. Is this behaviour normal ?

Comment: How _exactly_ did you try to replace it? FTP/SFTP? Some WP internal editor to edit files "online", something provided by an extra plugin, ...? _"didn't allow"_ - means you got an error message, or what exactly?

Comment: _"what are the alternative methods or workarounds that I can use to achieve this?"_ - usually this would be done via the PHP configuration for the server, or the specific hosting package.

Comment: I downloaded wp-config.php, added line I need, tried to put it in back. Permission to do this was denied.

Comment: As a web developer you should have enough permission to edit wp-config. Are you using a file management system such as ctPanel's?

Comment: I've tried using ftp connection from terminal. As a Mac beginner, I had to learn it.

Comment: If you're using a shared hosting environment which has access to something like cPanel, as Martin mentions above (or any other kind of web-based control panel), you should be able to edit it within the web-based file manager available in cPanel (or Plesk, or any other of the numerous hosting panels shared hosts use).  What kind of permissions error are you getting, how did you try to "put it back" exactly?  Did you make sure to overwrite the existing file?

Comment: If you're in terminal and you can SSH into your server, you can connect that way and then run `nano wp-config.php` to open a basic text editor that'd let you edit the `wp-config.php` file.  Once you're in there, you can add this line to the top of the file:
`define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');` (change it to whatever amount you want), then press CMD+X to exit (press Y to save the file)

Comment: You have [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77343338/231316) that is basically asking the same thing, please don't double-post.

Comment: First of all Im desperate and this is addressing different issue,
second if it does not get answered with in a day I lose money, 
third If it gets answered third time I can delete the other questions

Comment: I apologize for any confusion. While I was able to perform actions smoothly through the FTP terminal, I mistakenly assumed that connecting to the FTP server from Finder would yield the same results. However, I've managed to find a workaround to access the server through Finder.